# mongoose findOneAndUpdate return matched subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to modify one subdocument in my schema. In this subdocument i have stored a key for keep relationship with other document. The second document will modified only if the first it's modified. I try to do this with findOneAndUpdate.

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: ReceivingId,
            "friendship": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "_id": FriendshipId
                    , "verse": 1
                    , "status": "pending"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$set": {
                "friendship.$.status": "accepted",
                "friendship.$.began": util.moment().toDate()
            },
            "$unset": {"friendship.$.verse": ""}
        }, {"new": true})
        .select('friendship.$')
        .exec()
        .then(function Query(upReceiving) {

            if (!upReceiving)
                throw new Error({status: 304, message: "No friendship update"});

            var ApplicantId = upReceiving.friendship.friend;
            console.log("Sender ID", upReceiving);

            return User.findOneAndUpdate({          //Query
                _id: ApplicantId,
                "friendship": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "friend": ReceivingId,
                        "status": "pending"
                    }
                }

            }, {                            //Update
                "$set": {
                    "friendship.$.status": "accepted",
                    "friendship.$.began": util.moment().toDate()
                }

            }, {"select": "friendship.$", "new": true}).exec();

        })
        .then(function Query(upApplicant) {

            if (!upApplicant)
                return res.status(304).json({message: "No friendship update"});

            res.json({message: "Friendship accepted", friendship: {sender: upApplicant._id, receiver: ReceivingId}});

        }, function Error(err) {

            var status = 500;

            if (undefined !== err.status)
                status = err.status;

            console.log(err);
            res.status(status).json(err);
        });
```

The first update work, but the select statement with $ operator doesn't return the  subdocument found from the query.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was reading your code, and I have a doubt about it,

does the field "upReceiving.friendship.**friend**" contains a valid ObjectId?

i'm asking this because I saw the line:

```
var ApplicantId = upReceiving.friendship.friend;
```

and then, you are trying to find a document using that field like ObjectId

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
            _id: ApplicantId,..
```

Comment: No, it doesn't contain the value because the findOneAndUpdate doesn't return me the subdocument find by the query. I would do that. I would the findOneAndUpdate return me the matched and modified subdocument.